# iCloud alternative for ios/mac developers

Tags: ios, cloud, synchronization, software-design, icloud

I'm thinking of an ios/mac application.

My application need to sync the data between devices and mac. The reason I rule out iCloud because, it is only for osx 10.7, I don't want to miss 10.6 or 10.5 users.

Also I don't want to host the webserver as of now. And the data are personal and media heavy (photos & videos)

It will be an app based on Core-data Framework with media files.

I considered a few, since I never implemented syncing other than iCloud, looking for suggestions.

- Evernote is a good option but, free account storage might not enough for
  the users.
- Dropbox is a good option, but I'm not very sure about the support for sync (core-data, sqlite db - any success stories?)
- Zsync - Not updated recently, no cloud (can be synced with mac app? correct me if i'm wrong. There will be users with iDevices and NO Mac?)
- NO-SQL - Couchbase alike approach with dropbox?

**Updated  7th Jul '12:**

I recently found a new opensourced framework called [TICoreDataSync](https://github.com/nothirst/TICoreDataSync), I haven't tested it yet. Will check and update in coming weeks.

Comment: Have you found any interesting options for this?

Comment: @BlackRider unfortunately NO :-( iCloud + Coredata is still a pain.

Comment: @BlackRider My app holds users' private information, I don't think I would like to host/hire backend service. I just want to provide an option to sync/backup data to their space. I don't want to own, or responsible for data. iCloud is the best solution if it works.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Dropbox to sync data between devices and OS's:

Dropbox API is useful sharing.  (2GB free storage)
http://dropbox.com/api

Microsoft SkyDrive  (25GB free storage) 
I create sample Mac OS X application see: https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK/issues/5

Comment: Official sites for MS SkyDrive:
http://dev.live.com/

https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK

Live Interactive SDK at: http://isdk.dev.live.com/